# convert a javascript function to a web worker

Tags: javascript, php, web-worker

I have this javascript function  used for notification alert.
here is what it does
-- uses Ajax to connect to php
-- php sends a javascript code
-- code when executed using eval(code) updates a div with new notifications

Javascript code

```
function LOAD_NOTIFICATIONS(uid){
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var sendData = { action : 'LoadUserNotifications' , uid : uid } ;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'config/ajax/loader.php',
        cache: false,
        data: sendData,
        success: function(retData){
            eval(retData);
        }
    });
});

setTimeout('LOAD_NOTIFICATIONS(' + uid + ')', 10000 );
    //Recheck every 10 secs
}
```

PHP Server

```
if($action == 'LoadUserNotifications'){
    $uid = clean($_POST['uid']) ;
    $Notifications = LoadUserNotifications($uid) ;

    $count = $Notifications[0] ;
    $html = $Notifications[1] ;

    $ret = "
    $('#NotificationCount').html('$count').css('visibility','visible');
    $('#notifynav').html(\"$html\");  // Update notification Div
    " ;

    if($count == 0){
        $ret = "
        $('#NotificationCount').css('visibility','hidden');
        $('#notifynav').html(\"<li><a href='' class='false' onclick='return false' >no                 notification</a></li>\"); " ;
    }
    echo '$(function(){'.$ret.'});' ;
    exit();
}
```

Now the thing is how do i convert this piece of javascript function to a webworker to perform the same task.

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/

Answer (score 1):

A web worker cannot modify the DOM in any way.  So, you cannot convert this to a web worker that will do the same thing.  Only the main JS thread can modify the DOM.

In fact, I don't see any advantage to using a web worker for this task.  You can simply use the asynchronous ajax call and then process the result when the ajax call returns your data.  You could use a web worker to make the ajax call and then message the results of the ajax call back to the main thread to then the DOM, but that is just more complicated with no particular advantages.  It wouldn't be any more responsive.

FYI, it is generally safer to set the timer for the next ajax call after the completion of the first one.  This prevents any piling up of ajax calls if the response ever takes longer than your interval (10 seconds in your case).